# LKM Implicit declaration of function stat

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am currently writing a Linux Kernel Module (for the first time).

I am trying to use the stat function. I understand that regular imports are not going to work in Kernel code, so I imported their equivalent (that is what I thought...):

```
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
```

I don't get any error about the imports directly, but I get the following messages:

- **error: implicit declaration of function ‘stat’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]**
- **error: ‘errno’ undeclared (first use in this function)**

For the two lines respectively:

```
int ret = stat(pathname, statbuf);
```

and

```
errno = ENOENT;
```

Any help woule be welcome.

Thank you.

PS: I am working on Kali 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 but I am trying to write something generic, that could work on multiple versions of Linux.

Comment: If you're writing a system-call, then it should return the negative error code on error. E.g. `return -ENOENT;` if you want the system-call to fail with `errno` set to `ENOENT`.

Comment: Thank you. But I read that stat is returning -1 in case of error AND setting errno. That is why I was trying to do both. Should I just return ENOENT?

Comment: Well first of all `stat` is the *user-space* system-call, what you should use instead I don't know myself. Secondly, system-calls should return the *negative* error code on error, as explained in my previous comment. Try looking at a few example system-calls (if that's what you're writing) to see how they do it. System-calls and error handling is handled very differently inside the kernel than from user-space.

Comment: I read the stat source code and it does exactly what you said. Thank you. I get it.